# Monitoring process interference Factory's instance initialization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, rspec, factory, factory-bot

In my project, the **user** will have many **items**, which have an onshelf_at attribute default to `DateTime.now` at its creation.

```
# item.rb
class Item < ActiveRecord::Base

  before_create :calculate_onshelf_time

  default_scope :order => 'items.onshelf_at DESC'

  def calculate_onshelf_time
    self.onshelf_at = DateTime.now
  end

end
```

In the user model test, I tried to convince myself the retrieved order is indeed `items.onshelf_at DESC`. So I made the following snippet, but the result turned out to be reverse. (namely `[@item1, @item2]`)

```
# spec/models/user_spec.rb
before :each do
  @user = User.create(@attr)
  @item1 = Factory(:item, :owner=>@user, :onshelf_at => 2.days.ago, :created_at => 2.days.ago)
  @item2 = Factory(:item, :owner=>@user, :onshelf_at => 1.day.ago, :created_at => 1.day.ago)        
end


it "should have the right items in the right order" do
  @user.items.should == [@item2, @item1]
end
```

I checked the console, and found that **onshelf_at** wasn't listening to the instance initialization of Factory Girl. In its stead, it followed **before_create** rule, and valued to the time when test was run!

```
Failure/Error: @user.items.should == [@item2, @item1]
   expected: [#<Item id: 2, description: "this is an item", img_link: "http://www.example.com/photos/some_pic.jpg", category_id: 5, onshelf: true, created_at: "2011-11-20 11:19:15", updated_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", onshelf_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", owner_id: 1>, #<Item id: 1, description: "this is an item", img_link: "http://www.example.com/photos/some_pic.jpg", category_id: 5, onshelf: true, created_at: "2011-11-19 11:19:15", updated_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", onshelf_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", owner_id: 1>]
        got: [#<Item id: 1, description: "this is an item", img_link: "http://www.example.com/photos/some_pic.jpg", category_id: 5, onshelf: true, created_at: "2011-11-19 11:19:15", updated_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", onshelf_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", owner_id: 1>, #<Item id: 2, description: "this is an item", img_link: "http://www.example.com/photos/some_pic.jpg", category_id: 5, onshelf: true, created_at: "2011-11-20 11:19:15", updated_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", onshelf_at: "2011-11-21 11:19:15", owner_id: 1>] (using ==)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick fix would be to add a condition to your `calculate_onshelf_time` method:

```
 self.onshelf_at = DateTime.now if self.onshelf_at.nil?
```

But - you don't even need all this. If you can (that is, if you have control over the schema), replace the `onshelf_at` attribute with a  `created_at` column, which will automatically be set by Rails at the time of creation. If you're using migrations:

```
 create_table :foo do |t|
   # ...
   t.timestamps
 end
```

will add `created_at` and `updated_at` timestamps to the model.

Comment: It works! Thanks! Can you also tell what magic do you do, and why I failed? I don't quite get how FactoryGirl instance initialization works.

Comment: Is it that, Factory assign to those attributes, and **then** create model instance?

Comment: If you're referring to the first solution - factory_girl creates a new object, assigns all attributes as specified, then calls `save` on the model - which then triggers the `before_create` callback, which proceeds to overwrite the `onshelf_at` attribute. My solution simply checks if it already has a value, and only assigns one if it doesn't. But again, I'd really suggest to simply use the automatic timestamps baked into Rails instead.

Comment: I need the on `onshelf_at` attribute in the later development. I have a concern about the first solution though. If my teammate or me myself accidentally assign a value to `onshelf_at`, then the value won't be same as (or close to) `created_at` at creation. And I don't really prefer to use `created_at` instead before `onshelf_at` is manually assign a value later.